# iPad : Unable to implement variants of Portrait Orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4

I need to implement both variants of my Portrait orientation in iPad app.

I am using the code shown below to implement both `Portrait` and `PortraitUpsideDown` orientations.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation ==  UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

But orientation does not change when Orientation is PortraitUpsideDown.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working.

Added both the variants of Portrait Orientations to `Supported Interface Orientation` to my info.plist for my app.

This has worked for me.

Hope this helps everyone.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
return UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)
```

which is just a macro for what you're trying to get.I'm not sure both will work on simulator.

Comment: @suprandr: Thanks for the input. I have tried even this. But doesnt help. What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you try it on the device? Also, did you try triggering a rotation on the simulator before checking? Just to know if it's the simulator which is not pushing the correct orientation

Comment: @suprandr: I didnt try on device but as such I have tried checking by triggering rotation on simulator, but it doesnt seem to work. so what else can be done?

Comment: @suprandr: Will your answer work on device if I write `return UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)` under `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is to call on the viewDidLoad

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];`
 But I am not sure this will work better. I suspect that the problem is related to the use of this method on the simulator.
Did you try to rotate it before checking it's values (using cmd+arrows)?

Comment: Yup tried that (cmd+arrows) but didnt work out. I am yet to try out `[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];`